# How to handle maximum number of connections issue for http client?

Tags: linux, multithreading, go, fork, goroutine

We have a http GET handler(`ProductHandler`) that in turn uses http client to connect to another server.

```
type ProductHandler struct {
    service1       Service1
    service2       Service2
}


type Service2 struct {
    field1             int
    field2             string
    client             CustomHttpClient
}
```

`CustomHttpClient` uses `http.Client` type from `https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go`

---

As `http.Client` is concurrent safe, we are using single http client for multiple GET requests, by registering `ProductHandler{}` for GET requests.

GET requests are served by `http.Server` from `https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go`

But the problem is, `http.Client` limits the number of GET requests served by `ProductHandler`, due to number of file descriptors in Linux(default 1024), which are limited. To be specific, `MaxConnsPerHost` in `http.Transport` limited by Linux file descriptors.

---

How to address the problem of GET requests limited by number of file descriptors in `CustomHttpClient`? raising `ulimit` is just a work around...

Comment: "How to address the problem of GET requests limited by number of file descriptors in CustomHttpClient? raising ulimit is just a work around..." is like asking "How to address the problem of information transfer limited by the speed of light? Raising the vacuum light speed is just a work around". Some limits are limits because they limit things and the reason they exist is to limit, not to not limit.

Comment: Raising `ulimit` is not a workaround. Trying to get out of `ulimit` in your Go code is a workaround